# Textarea text dissapear test with Cypress

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, cypress, textarea

how can I test the Textarea text which is disappearing after you start to write something?

after I write something nothing changes on showed dom.

[image]

I want to test that `Enter a comment.` texts disappearing.
[image]

Thank you for advices...

Comment: Why are you testing the internals of the textarea element?

Comment: requirements, they wanted to know after you add any character then enter a comment text must disappear. Just it.

Comment: And yet, the answer you accepted does not do that. If you repeat `.should('have.attr','placeholder','Enter a comment.')` it still passes - how does that prove that it has disappeared?

Comment: yes, your right but I don't know any way to assert that, do you have any ideas?

Comment: As I mentioned at the start, you are testing the internals of the textarea. It cannot be done with javascript (so Cypress cannot do it). IMO you can only add snapshot testing to check the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @Prophet's answer:

I would test the placeholder and the value of the input, in that order.

```
cy.get('your textarea selector')
.should('have.attr','placeholder','Enter a comment.')
.type('stackoverflow')
.should('have.value','stackoverflow')
```

Edit: Checking if the textarea is empty before typing (more robust test).
Another option could be doing a .clear before the .type

```
cy.get('your textarea selector')
.should('have.attr','placeholder','Enter a comment.')
.should('have.value','')
.type('stackoverflow')
.should('have.value','stackoverflow')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code is working! But still, I can't test `enter a comment` text's existence.  place holders value is "" yes it's working but I wondering is there any way to test that existence :)

Comment: can I ask something? Instead of asserting values how can I put values into variables to use later?

Comment: There are two main ways: first, work with them inside a .then(($yieldedVariable)=>{}) closure, the other way is to save them with an @alias (cy.wrap('whatever').as('myAliasName) )  and save them for later in the code. This will help you: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Return-Values

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `value` attribute of that `textarea` element.
Something like the following:

```
theValue = textarea.getAttribute('value')
```

Comment: Please let me know if that worked for you

Comment: No unfortunately didn't work. But thank you for the try.

Comment: Strange. Do you mean you received empty value for the `value` attribute of the `textarea` element where some text was there?

Comment: it says syntax error, like `it's not a function`. It's strange nothing changes on the dom or CSS side. I don't know how to find and assert that text.

Comment: Well, I'm not really familiar with JavaScript, I'm sorry...

Comment: Your welcome and of course thank you again :)